# Should we choose XMPP or self-made server？

Tags: xmpp

I'm working on a project with IM feature. We build a self-made server with chat message and notification support. The clients (iphone, android and web) make long http connection with server to get IM message and system notification. We use Apache as connection management facility but encounter CLOSE_WAIT problem.
If we use open source XMPP server as openfire or ejabbered, we can get full IM and notification functionality. But we need effort to integrate with XMPP server and make facilities for web IM. Any suggestion for our project? Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When building internet based systems you should always try and use standardised protocol's, that's why the IETF is there, to ensure interoperability.

Despite the occasional comment that XMPP is difficult to use it's really not at all, it's simply streaming XML and therefore very extensible. Take a look at the list of libraries already available and I'm sure you'll be up and running with XMPP chat in just a few hours.

On servers, my recommendation would be ejabberd for high traffic, Prosody for ease of use and Isode for a commercial solution.

Another option is to use an XMPP hosting provider like ProcessOne, Cleartext for example.

Comment: Thanks for project names, i.e. Prosody. I agree with general idea, install ready server is simpler than develop (and debug, debug, debug)  own (socket) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your needs, XMPP is very flexible and can do a lot more than IM. Also it is standardized, which should make it easier to incorporate more services if needed later on. But if all you need is a simple chatroom for your logged in users it may be overkill. An alternative may be something really light weight like [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) or similar.

Faye is based on Node.js and Ruby/Rack, but I'm sure you can find similar things for other platforms if those don't suit you.